# Issue with NTP configuration

Tags: redhat, ntp, rhel6

I am working with RHEL-6 64 bit server. When using `ntpq -p` I get the following result:

```
$ ntpq -p
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

With RHEL 5.4 we were using a ntp configuration as below:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf
server <ip> prefer key <keyval>
```

But it is not working with the RHEL 6 ?

Comment: Are you sure ntpd is running?

Comment: Issue has solved, This is because I had the option “restrict default ignore” set in /etc/ntp.conf. ntpq. This makes ntpd ignore EVERYTHING, even queries to the loopback interface. Ntpq queries ntpd over the loopback interface at 127.0.0.1. To allow these local queries, add:

Answer (score 1):

If you have restrict default ignore set in ntp.conf, then it will ignore everything.